# Iterating over options and quoted/unquoted arguments passed to bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that uses getopt to parse its parameters. It correctly handles switches and long options, as well as arguments and quoted arguments, but I cannot figure out how to iterate over the options/arguments string returned by the backticks. Something like:

```
params=`getopt -o ab -l ccc  -- "$@"`
echo $params
for param in "$params"
do
echo $param
done
```

Will echo out `-a -- 'foo' 'foo bar'` when the script is invoked as `./a.sh -a foo "foo bar"`, but the loop rather than iterating over each separately will only run once over the entire string. Removing the double quotes:

```
for param in $params
```

will cause it to iterate like this:

```
-a
--
'foo'
'foo
bar'
```

ignoring the quoting around "foo bar". Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From the getopt manpage (at least the util-linux one:)

> Traditional  implementations  of  getopt(1)  are  unable  to  cope with
>   whitespace and other (shell-specific) special characters  in  arguments
>   and  non-option  parameters. To solve this problem, this implementation
>   can generate quoted output which must once again be interpreted by  the
>   shell  (usually by using the eval command). This has the effect of pre‐
>   serving those characters, but you must call getopt in a way that is  no
>   longer  compatible  with  other versions (the second or third format in
>   the SYNOPSIS).  To determine whether this enhanced version of getopt(1)
>   is installed, a special test option (-T) can be used.

Example:

```
$ getopt -- 'abc' -a -b 'foo bar' -c
-a -b -c -- 'foo bar'
```

So, you can see the output is quoted, ready to be used:

```
$ eval set -- "`getopt -- 'abc' -a -b 'foo bar' -c`"
$ for a; do echo "arg: $a"; done
arg: -a
arg: -b
arg: -c
arg: --
arg: foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `bash` builtin [`getopts`](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Also, for a nice example of using `getopt`, see [this script](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/contributed-scripts.html#USEGETOPT).