# Parse string into argument list just like if typed into console?

Tags: string, list, shell, split, arguments

I'm trying to parse the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS environment variable in Xcode 3.2 in 10.6.  It's a string of paths like:

```
"~/My Path with Spaces" /usr/local /myrootpath
```

I need to split this string, following all of the shell's quoting rules, so that I can loop over the argument list and prepend -I and then pass all of that to gcc like so:

```
gcc -I"~/Path with Spaces" -I/usr/local -I/myrootpath
```

I've studied awk, sed, set, $@, everything.  I thought this would have worked:

```
set -- $HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

for arg in $@  
do  
    echo "arg $i:$arg:" >> mytestfile.txt  
    let "i+=1"  
done
```

But it only splits on space so the result is:

```
arg :"~/Path:  
arg 1:with:  
arg 2:Spaces":  
arg 3:/usr/local:  
arg 4:/myrootpath:
```

I'm also curious if there is a gcc tool that sets the include path in one step.  I must be missing something basic.  Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS="-L/usr/lib -lfoo"
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER="blah"
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="\"/path with spaces\" /usr/include /home/user/includes"

eval set -- $HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

for arg in "$@"; do
  INCLUDE_STRING+="-I$arg "
done

g++ ${INCLUDE_STRING} ${OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS} -c ${GCC_PREFIX_HEADER}
```

Comment: did you mean `eval set -- ...`

Comment: in this particular case either would have worked since his paths don't start with '-'.  However, having `--` can only help so I added it. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Hey thanx!  Your solution led me to these pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297529/iterating-over-options-and-quoted-unquoted-arguments-passed-to-bash-script and http://stevemorin.blogspot.com/2006/04/bash-loop-through-parameters.html and I eventually cobbled a solution using eval or a function, which then uses shift on $1 and I will post it below.  I'm new so don't know how to give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but perl is everywhere...

```
$ cat prep.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($#ARGV>=0) {
print " -I\"";
print shift;
print "\"";
}

$ echo $A
"a b c" x y

$ perl -e '$cmd="./prep.pl ".$ENV{"A"}; $args= `$cmd`; print("gcc ".$args);'
gcc  -I"a b c" -I"x" -I"y"
```

If you replace the last print with system then I think you will get what you want (assuming you add something for gcc to actually complile).

e.g.

```
$ perl -e '$cmd="./prep.pl ".$ENV{"A"}; $args= `$cmd`; system("gcc ".$args." 1.c");'
```

Probably not the ideal solution, but hey, it's late.

Comment: Hmmm I think your solution would work, unfortunately I don't know perl and am having a hard time testing it.  I'm kind of new to stack exchange so just wanted to say hi and thanx for your quick response, hopefully your answer will help others who arrive at this page :-)

Answer (score 0):

thanx for your quick responses guys!
after sleeping on it, I arrived at a solution using eval and shift.
the trick is, if you access $1 it works, but if you loop over $* or $@ it fails.
if anyone knows why the $1 shift method works, an explanation might help others.
then I append the prepended strings to to a final string with printf.

```
#this script will create a prefix.h.gch precompiled
#header in the project's directory.

cd "${PROJECT_DIR}"

eval set -- $HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

HEADER_SEARCH_STRING=""  
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do  
    HEADER_SEARCH_STRING=HEADER_SEARCH_STRING printf %s "-I\"$1\" "  
    shift  
done

g++ ${HEADER_SEARCH_STRING} ${OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS} -c ${GCC_PREFIX_HEADER}
```

#this is an alternate example of doing the same thing with a function:

```
TESTVAR="\"hello there\" a b /my/path"

TOKENS=""  
function tokenize {  
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do  
        TOKENS=TOKENS printf %s "-I\"$1\" "  
        #TOKENS=TOKENS echo "-I\""$1"\""  
        #echo "$1"  
        shift  
    done  
}

eval tokenize $TESTVAR

echo $TOKENS
```

Comment: Now that I know exactly what you are looking for (not just an example script), I updated my code to do exactly what you want. There is no need to use shift.  Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414898/parse-string-into-argument-list-just-like-if-typed-into-console/4414905#4414905